# How to Load Database Images/Text from bottom up? (Newest posts first)

Tags: php, html, sql

I have code in which a user can upload a file/image and text, and then it displays onto the page. I would like for the newest uploaded posts to show first and oldest last, so basically from the bottom up. Here is my code where I am loading it normally:

PHP/SQL:

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "boxofmem_GMSConnect");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM images";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<div id='img_div'>";
    echo "<p style='font-family:Roboto;color:white;font-size:20px;'>".$row['text']."</p>";
    echo "<img src='images/".$row['image']."' ' style='width:100%;height:100%;'>";
    echo "</div>";
}

?>
```

FIELDS:

ID (int:11)
IMAGE (BLOB)
TEXT (TEXT)

Comment: Is that your password in there? You have changed it, haven’t you?

Comment: @Manngo of course!

Answer (score 5):

If you mean the reverse order, that’s done in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY something DESC
```

where `something` is the actual field you want to sort. It may be the primary key or a date.

In your case, the `ID` column appears to be the primary key, and is probably auto-incremented. That means recent records have higher values. To display the most recent first:

```
SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY ID DESC
```

the `ORDER BY` clause, which is optional, but always the last clause of an SQL statement, determines the sort order. The default order is ascending `ASC`, and is implied if you don’t specify a direction.

`DESC` reverses the order. This will bring the most recent to the top.

Comment: I understand for the most part besides the "something" part.

Comment: If you list the actual fields in your `images` table, I can clarify that in the answer.

Comment: @ReeceFox its basically a column where you can specify the order of your result.

Comment: @Manngo so in this case would something be equal to the field "image" ?

Comment: Sorry, I missed your next comment. No, I would say that it is `ID`. If you use `image` it would look random, because it will try to sort by the image binary data.

Comment: @Manngo this is strange. For some reason, ID did not work, but remained everything the same, and image did work.

Comment: What happens if you change `DESC` to `ASC`? You could also try `SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY ID DESC` or `ASC` in PHPMyAdmin to check your results. Remember `ASC` is optional as it’s implied.

Comment: @Manngo it turns out, sorted by image does mean it is by the name of the image. What are my options? ID is not doing anything :(

Comment: @Manngo I am not sure why the ID is not working, and I do not know where to go about from here

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY ID DESC`? Just a few rows.

Answer (score 0):

Add a field to your table called something like recordCreatedWhen.  You didn't specify your database engine, but use whatever datatype it has that means `date and time`.  Give it a default value of the current date and time.  Pretty well every database engine out there allows you to do what I just said.

@Manngo already told you about `order by` clauses.  In this case, it would be

```
order by recordCreatedWhen desc
```